# Can we assign numeric values to wso2 claims?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

There are some claims such as the expiry date of the token which is a numeric value.
I created a new claim using wso2 UI, however, even if I type in a numeric value, I end up with a string value in my token.

I might have missed something, in that case, could anyone help me make my claim a numeric value type?
(if it's possible of course)

Comment: what is the IS version you are using

Comment: I think the latest, wso2 is 6.1.0